# Customizing Woocommerce Email

Tags: plugin-development

I want to change the layout and design of woocommerce emails. I am not able to find right article to get help. Also i am a beginner to wordpress plugin development. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd copy the email template files from /`wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails` to your theme `/wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME/woocommerce/emails/` and modify the files directly but as a beginner I recommend just buying a plugin and design your emails within a few minutes without coding: https://etzelstorfer.com/en/downloads/wp-html-mail-woocommerce/